# How to split a list in python based on the sum of elements in the list?

Tags: python-2.7

list L=[1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2]
to split the list L into sublist according to the cumulative sum of elements equal to 4. i.e the list should be split as S=[[1,2,1],[2,2],[1,1,2]]

Comment: How should `[2,1,2,1]` be split?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this code but for sure there are some improvements that can be done:

```
cumulativesum=4
score1=0
S=[]
sublist=[]
for element in L:
    score1=score1+int(element)
    if score1 < cumulativesum:
        sublist.append(element)
    elif score1 == cumulativesum:
        sublist.append(element)
        S.append(sublist)
        sublist=[]
        score1=0
    else:
        S.append(sublist)
        sublist=[]
    score1=0
```

Basically for each element of the list L you will add the element to a sublist and then when you reach the cumulativesum the sublist will be close and added to the S (the list with results).